# Any chance of expanding data types for mobility

Tags: mobility

I love the gem and how it works, I was just wondering if there was any existing or planned functionality to specify data types other than `text` and `string` for the translations (stored in `mobility_[type]_translations`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not documented, but it's not hard to support other types like Integer, Float, etc.

e.g. for Integer, you'd have to create a table like this:

```
  create_table "mobility_integer_translations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "locale", null: false
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.integer "value"
    t.string "translatable_type"
    t.bigint "translatable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["translatable_id", "translatable_type", "key"], name: "index_mobility_string_translations_on_translatable_attribute"
    t.index ["translatable_id", "translatable_type", "locale", "key"], name: "index_mobility_string_translations_on_keys", unique: true
    t.index ["translatable_type", "key", "value", "locale"], name: "index_mobility_string_translations_on_query_keys"
  end
```

then you'd need to create a class for this table:

```
module Mobility
  module Backends
    class ActiveRecord::KeyValue
      class IntegerTranslation < Translation
        self.table_name = "mobility_integer_translations"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I believe this should be enough, and I *think* you should be able to just do this (assuming your config has `key_value` as the backend):

```
translates :foo, type: :integer
```

There's nothing in Mobility itself that actually *says* you can't use another translation class, it's just that these are not offered out-of-the-box. Probably this should be added to the Wiki somewhere.

Comment: Oooh, that is a rather neat solution!